# How does Spring Boot load changes in code without restarting the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This was an interview question to me that , is it possible that some changes you made in your code and it is an spring boot application, and without restarting the server you are able to get those changes.?
if yes, then how is it possible in spring boot.

I want to know that how is it possible in Spring Boot.?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add spring-boot-devtools module to your project, which includes LiveReload server which can be used to trigger a browser refresh whenever a resource has been changed.You can download browser extensions from [livereload.com](http://livereload.com).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 7):

You only need to add `devtool` dependency in `pom.xml` and yml file property:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

# for not restarting the server every time
spring.devtools.restart.enabled:  false
```

Answer (score 4):

you may want to check [here spring dev tool](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

Notice:

1. no matter what, when you have change to your java code, the server need to be restarted, spring dev tool just help you to reload it
2. if it is jsp then you do not have to restart server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using intellij, the follow dependency setting works for me.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Good answer :) But it's not related to IntelliJ , it's a maven plugin for spring boot development

Comment: Thank you for the comment, really cool to know that's a solution independent on IDE, I've actually been curious why fg78nc's anwser didn't work for me, any idea what's the effect of tag <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional> in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps and it should work

1. Add the following to pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>       
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
   ```
2. In application.properties

   spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true

Note : Ensure spring boot is restarted once after making changes to the application.properties file.

For additional information please check
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

Answer (score 0):

Just enable Build Automatically in the Project tab in STS, if you have the dependency in your pom.xml