# Spring boot hot reloading does not work in InteliJ Community edition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to have spring boot auto restart the server when my classes are updated. I already have seen the following answer:

[How does Spring Boot load changes in code without restarting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018873/how-does-spring-boot-load-changes-in-code-without-restarting-the-server/45019249)

My pom file has the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following settings enabled in Intelij:

[image]

And also:

[image]

When I now spin up the server I get the following:

Notice in the logs:

> 2021-12-18 15:18:42.624  INFO 4204 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is
> running on port 35729

But now when I make changes to any of the files in the package where my main method is and subpackages (for example: Test controller) my server does not get reloaded.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: sorry (stupid question!?), but IntelliJ Ultimate? (not Community!?)

Comment: @xerx593 It is Community edition, is this only for ultimate?

Comment: yeah, ;( "spring support only in Ultimate"

Comment: @xerx593 Okay but with ultimate version it would restart the server when I change one of the classes right?

Comment: (i also use community-only, but) "never heard complaints" :-)

Comment: Does this work in your community edition?

Comment: no, it doesn't! (we can little (ugly) hack))...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [IntelliJ Edition Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) shows, Community Edition doesn't "support":

> Spring, Jakarta EE, Java EE, Micronaut, Quarkus, Helidon and more...

We can (little ugly, because an exception "flies", the restart happens (at least)2 times ..depending how long the build/compilation takes) "hack".

Running a *maven `spring-boot:run` configuration*, we can:

- (better) Deactivate the shown settings: Save on Compile, "Allow auto make on running..." (we can also leave, but the result/number of restarts will be less predictable:)
- Trigger an (additional) "(Re-)build module/project" build, or a `mvn process-classes` (or something, that "touches the classpath").