# Spring boot hot reloading does not work in InteliJ Ultimate edition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I previously had a problem with the community edition of  InteliJ. The problem was that hot swapping didn't work via spring boot devtools (i.e. after updating a class the server should only update those classes and not restart).

[Spring boot hot reloading does not work in InteliJ Community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404191/spring-boot-hot-reloading-does-not-work-in-intelij)

Someone told me this was due to the community edition. After installing the ultimate edition my problem remains the same.

Details:

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition),
Windows 10

Settings > compiler > build project automatically > enabled

Settings > advanced > allow auto-make start if developed app is currently running > enabled

Anyone has a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my experience some classes can not be hotloaded, for example static classes, scheduler and rest controller

maybe that could help

Comment: It was indeed a controller, other classes work thanks for the tip!